# Null Pointer Exception : android.widget.Button

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

in my problem, I have a widget button. if the button I'm click it will go to the next activity, but after I clicked my Application has Stopped. The indicated was about

> NullPointerException : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

**Below My Code**

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuList;
String searchkey;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listing);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    searchkey = extras.getString("txtsearch").toString();
    //rename actionbar title to search keyword
    setTitle("Hasil Pencarian " + searchkey);
    //URL with search key
    menuList = new ArrayList<>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    BtnDetail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDetail);
    BtnDetail.setOnClickListener(this);
    new GetMenu().execute();
}
public void onClick (View v){
    if (v.getId()==R.id.btnDetail)
    {
        Intent maps = new Intent(this,MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(maps);
    }
}

private class GetMenu extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Listing.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading,, Please Wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        String url_search = "http://10.0.2.2/search/search.php?txtsearch="+searchkey;
        Log.e(TAG,url_search);
        //Making request to url and getting response

        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url_search);
        Log.e(TAG,"Response from URL :" +jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null){
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                // Getting JSON Array node name
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString("menu_kuliner.kd_kuliner");
                    String menu = c.getString("menu_kuliner.menu");
                    String harga = c.getString("menu_kuliner.harga");
                    String kuliner = c.getString("nama_kuliner.nm_kuliner");
                    String alamat = c.getString("nama_kuliner.alamat");
                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("menu_kuliner.kd_kuliner", id);
                    contact.put("menu_kuliner.menu", menu);
                    contact.put("menu_kuliner.harga", harga);
                    contact.put("nama_kuliner.nm_kuliner", kuliner);
                    contact.put("nama_kuliner.alamat", alamat);
                    // adding contact to contact list
                    menuList.add(contact);
            }
            //if JSON format error
        } catch (final JSONException e){
                Log.e(TAG,"JSON Parsing Error :" +e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "JSON Parsing Error :" +e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
    } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldnt get JSON From Server !");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldnt get JSON From Server ! Check Logcat for possible Error",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
}

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute (Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();


    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            Listing.this, menuList, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{"menu_kuliner.kd_kuliner", "menu_kuliner.menu", "menu_kuliner.harga", "nama_kuliner.nm_kuliner", "nama_kuliner.alamat"}, //<= ARRAY LIST
            new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.menu, R.id.harga, R.id.kuliner, R.id.alamat});
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

}

**This is my Activity_listing.xml**

```
android:id="@+id/activity_listing"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Listing" >

    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

**This is my list_item.xml**

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize=" 17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/harga"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14dip" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/kuliner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14dip" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/alamat"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14dip" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**androidManifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBrGERGDjAf2XKeS9Q_MGd24hOX_PUTKpQ" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Listing">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MapsActivity">

    </activity>
</application>
```

**EDIT**

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuList;
String searchkey;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listing);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    searchkey = extras.getString("txtsearch").toString();
    //rename actionbar title to search keyword
    setTitle("Hasil Pencarian " + searchkey);
    //URL with search key
    menuList = new ArrayList<>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView <?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if( view.getId()== R.id.btnDetail)
            {
                Intent maps = new Intent(Listing.this,MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(maps);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: button is in individual layout, you cannot directly reference that in the activity, you need to set click listener inside the adaptor,

Comment: You have not declared the button properly

Comment: how i must declared the button properly ?? @Akshay

Comment: where i must set click listener in my case ?? @Sanoop

Comment: Please show your adaptor code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list item click listener for handling click events for listview

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if( view.getId() == R.id.btnDetail ) {
               Intent maps = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
               startActivity(maps);
            }
        }
    });
```

If you want the click listener to be handled via button click use above code , or you can remove the if condition for checking the button id and directly call the maps activity from the event handler. .

Comment: owh.. adaptor for new button, isn't ? I don't have that..
so, I  have to create a separate adapter to apply the button to work, right? @Sanoop

Comment: Yes, Exactly @RandyWiratama

Comment: I've added a new adaptor with the name Adp_Listing.java for a new button.. so,, where I must call my new Adp_Listing.java ?? @Sanoop

Comment: when I click the button,, my application not change to the next activity.. what's wrong ?? @Sanoop

Comment: Can you post your latest code? @RandyWiratama

Comment: may I talk privately with you ?? @Sanoop

Comment: this is my latest code.. I'm just added Adp_Listing.java @Sanoop

Comment: @RandyWiratama Oh No!! You just created a new activity, thats wrong!! What i meant is an adaptor

Comment: @RandyWiratama check [this](http://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial) Its a good tutorial for adaptor for listview

Comment: @RandyWiratama , Is it a requirement to add button for each layout? Can you show what you want to achieve? Do you have any screenshot? or drawing anything?

Comment: in here,, i don't understand what the function the adaptor,, i just want to show a map with button... not listview.. @Sanoop

Comment: Then why did you placed the button inside the list item xml? You can directly place that inside the activity xml right?

Comment: @RandyWiratama You can place the button below the listview, and set on click listener.

Comment: no,, i will explain you how may application work.. activity main xml just for searching page,, after doing search data, data will show (list_item), and on this page the button will be get a map...
so far,, activity main to list_item no obstacles, but from list_item to activity maps cannot work..

Comment: `menuList = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        BtnDetail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDetail);
        BtnDetail.setOnClickListener(this);`
like that ?? @Sanoop

Comment: @RandyWiratama Please check edit

Comment: if you want the click listener to be handled via button click use above code i have provided, or you can remove the if condition for checking the button id and directly call the map activity from the event handler. @RandyWiratama

Comment: which one do you edit @Sanoop ??

Comment: Last portion of my answer, below the **Edit** word, you that in the main activity. @RandyWiratama

Comment: why in my program there some error after I added the code above ??
error in `startActivity(MapsActivity.class);' @Sanoop

Comment: What error are you getting @RandyWiratama

Comment: in the startActivity,, it's just can be applied with Intent @Sanoop

Comment: Sorry? @RandyWiratama Can you put the error message?

Comment: OK replace `this` with `MainActivity.this` @RandyWiratama in the intent

Comment: @RandyWiratama Check the new edit, it should work

Comment: Error:(61, 21) error: no suitable method found for startActivity(Class<MapsActivity>)
method Context.startActivity(Intent) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Class<MapsActivity> cannot be converted to Intent)
method ContextWrapper.startActivity(Intent) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Class<MapsActivity> cannot be converted to Intent)
method Activity.startActivity(Intent) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Class<MapsActivity> cannot be converted to Intent) -- This is my error message @ Sanoop

Comment: so.. @Sanoop what about the adaptor ?? I still confuse..

Comment: This is a new question, you should ask  a new question with this, I have helped you with the current one. Please appreciate by up voting and accepting the answer, And will help you with the new question. @RandyWiratama

Comment: @RandyWiratama No need for adaptor anymore, thats what the edit part does.

Comment: @RandyWiratama Did you replace `this` with `MainActivity.this` in the intent

Comment: yes,, I do @Sanoop

Comment: startActivity(MapsActivity.this); Like that ?

Comment: No N0 !! @RandyWiratama `Intent maps = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);` and start by `startActivity(maps);`

Comment: Please check my answer now @RandyWiratama

Comment: yess,, I did,, but i get error in startActivity(maps) @Sanoop

Comment: my program still error in     Intent maps = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);  He said MainActivity is not enclosing class.. @Sanoop

Comment: From which activity are calling this code? @RandyWiratama

Comment: ohh,, I'm sorry @Sanoop..My Fault.. this alright..

Comment: All good? :) Please appreciate my effort by upvoting @RandyWiratama

Comment: the button still not work.. it's not work how it should be..